# Using SCPs to restrict access to some EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I want to spin up some EC2 instances on my organisation with some heavily sensitive data.

AFAIK, EC2 do not make use of resource based policies.

My question is whether one can leverage Service Control Policies to make those EC2 (with specific attributes, e.g. having a specific name pattern or some specific tag values) accessible only by a selected group of IAM users.

What I want to prohibit is other users being able to view metadata.

Comment: How do users "access" the instances? Do they connect with SSH, or do they use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager (which is controlled by IAM and tracked by AWS)?

Comment: Please note that information stored on an Amazon EC2 instance is actually not on the instance but rather is stored on an Amazon EBS Volume, so permissions would need to be managed around who can snapshot/restore the volumes too.